# Limiting number of "users" that an IAM user can create

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

How to limit the number of users that an IAM user can create.

For Example: A user can only create a single user A'

I have tried to use allow and deny tag in Effects but it will deny user creation at all.

I can handle that with programming but that is not an option as: a user can be created through GUI or CLI which I don't have the track of that user is created.

I want to know is there a policy where I can restrict the number of users that an IAM user can create?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible using IAM policy. `Effect` for `"Action": "iam:CreateUser"` can be either Allow or Deny which you've already tested. You will need to write custom code to control number of IAM users another IAM user can create.

Comment: Yes, that the only thing I want.

Answer (score 0):

As Athar said, is it not possible with IAM only.
I would say you can read the CloudTrail log, extract the "Create User" events with a Lambda, store them in a Database and if the number exceeds the limit send an alarm.
It won't prevent it, but at least you will know.